# Is this the right way to implement ElGamal scheme over Elliptic Curves over prime field?

Tags: elliptic-curves, cryptanalysis, algorithm-design

I'm fairly new to Cryptography, especially elliptic curves in general. I learned to do Point Multiplication, Scalar Multiplication and also programmatically implemented them. But I was trying to do ElGamal scheme because I felt intrigued by the subtlety of it.
The problem that haunts me is this:
Suppose, I have a generator point G on an Elliptic Curve (say SECP256k1 or any curve) , an integer x, which is the private key of this scheme, and I generate the public key `P= [x]G` . Then, I encode the message to a single number (e) that will be surely less than `p`, the prime number of the field **(256 bit)**.

**ENCRYPTION** : I generate a random number **k**, less than **N**, where **N**, is the order of the curve, and also: `R = [k]P` . 
I also choose a point `C = [k]G`. Then I take the x coordinate of R, and do: `(x_coordinate of R*e) modulo p` -> this will be the cipher text.

**DECRYPTION**: I take the chosen point C, multiply it with x (private key) to recover the point R back, then I do :  `(cipher_text*((x_coordinate of R)^(-1) modulo p))modulo p` to recover `e` , the encoded message, which is then decoded back to plain text !

**MY CONCERNS:**
[1] Was that the right way to encode the message?
[2] If `x_coordinate of R * e` was smaller than `256` `bits` then modulo would output the same `x_coordinate of R*e` which can be **easily factored** on a computer, and `x_coordinate of R` could be recovered !

**EDITS:** 
What can be the maximum size of `x_coordinate of R * e` when taking modulo p ? I understand that **it should be less than p**, but even when I take blocks of plain text such that Rx*e alone exceeds ( **485 bits**)the bit size of p (**256 bits**) I'm **able** to recover the encoded message back ! I do not know the reason for this **creepy behaviour!!!** ? Sorry, I'm fairly new to the math of all this !!! ***BUT:*** If `x_coordinate of R*e` is of the order of **2000 bits** I totally **loose data** !!! Infact I am getting it wrong if thats the case!
**This is what gives me trouble:**

```
/************************
     Code for illustration of 
     my mathematical problem
******************/
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <gmpxx.h>

using namespace std;
mpz_class ModInverse(mpz_class a, mpz_class b)
{
    mpz_t inv;
    mpz_init(inv);
    mpz_invert(inv, a.get_mpz_t(), b.get_mpz_t());
    return mpz_class(inv);
}
int main()
{
      // Prime used by SECP256k1
      mpz_class p=mpz_class("115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007908834671663");
      //Let this be some encoded message ... 
      mpz_class msg=mpz_class("123115792089237316344566776544467896775567567584007908834671663758400790883");
      // Let this be the x coordinate of R
      mpz_class x=mpz_class("712164785702978780789493774073370493892893827485075314964804772812648384");

      cout<< "Encode Message :  "<< msg <<  endl;
      cout << "\nx coordinate of R * msg"<< msg*x << endl;
      cout << "Product bit length: " << mpz_class(msg*x).get_str(2).length()<< endl;
      // Bit length exceeds modulo bit length
      mpz_class cph=(msg*x)%p;
      cout << "Cipher : "<< cph<< endl;

      cout << "\nDecrypted message : "<<  (cph*ModInverse(x, p))%p<< endl;
      if ((cph*ModInverse(x, p))%p == msg){
      cout << "    Crypto successfull !!!"<< endl;
      }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
If `(x coordinate of R * e )` is less than p then with *sufficient amount* of cipher text of that form, can an attacker with some cryptanalysis crack it ??? I'm reading a message in blocks...

***Sorry If I'm wrong !!!***

Every help will be appreciated!!!

Comment: x_coordinate of R and $e$ are not necessarily prime numbers, you do not factor x_coordinate of R * e. And you do not spcecify how to encode the message.

Comment: @shumy: Thankyou for your reply! I use simple hex encoding!!!

Comment: @fgrieu Yes I wanted more information, therefore I decided to post a separate question... But I understood the concept only just recently... Sorry :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. It does not matter what encoding scheme you use for the message, as long as it is reversible: you should be able to recover the message from `e`.
2. Assume you do not know $e$ or $R_x$ (the x-coordinate of $R$). You are given $$e \cdot R_x \mod p$$
   For any possible message $e'$ that you could guess, there is some integer $n$ such that $$e'\cdot n \equiv  e \cdot R_x \mod p$$
   (exercise: what is this $n$?)

If you could determine which of $e$ and $e'$ was the correct message, then you would be able to tell which of $n$ and $R_x$ is the correct x-value of the shared secret $R$. But we assume that the attacker is not able to distinguish $R$ from a random point on the curve (this is the Decisional Diffe Hellman assumption).

Essentially, you do not need to worry about an adversary "factoring" $R_x \cdot e$, because in the integers mod $p$ there is not a unique way of factoring a number, for exactly the same reason that there is no unique way of factoring into rational numbers: $6 = 3\cdot 2$, but it also equals $4 \cdot \frac{2}{3}$ or $95 \cdot \frac{6}{95}$

Comment: Thankyou very much for your reply ! I'm naive to modular arithmetic... :( I do not know what n is...  Is it Modulo inverse of x coordinate over prime p or modulo inverse of e' over p... I tried plugging the values to the equations... but Im wrong !!!

Comment: $n$ is the resulting $R^{'}_{x}$ if you try to guess $e^{'}$. Even if you guess correct you cannot know that $n = R_{x}$.

Comment: @shumy : Sorry, Im unable to read your answer because javascript is not displaying math correctly ! but can you please see my edits !!! ?

Comment: Please see my edits!!!

Comment: In your edit, you are able to recover the message because you know `x`. An attacker would not. You loose data over 2000 bits because you can only encode ~2047 bits of data as an integer mod a 2048-bit prime. The amount of plaintext (as long as it is small enough to be encoded) is irellevant.

Comment: In particular, you can encrypt just 1 bit using this scheme. Say the message is always equal to `1` or `2`. From a ciphertext, how would an attacker decide which message was encrypted?

Comment: @Tjaden Hess: So the method I use for encrypting i.e. (x_coordinate of R * msg) mod p should be abandoned for msg > than one bit !? Please note that I was able to recover the message despite x_coordinate of R * msg is 485 bits and p is only 256 bits since as you pointed out I know x ... So what exactly will be the cut off bit limit of encoded msg in my circumstances... If I use one bit of msg then after encryption of entire message , ciphertext would be enormous and inefficient to transport... Thankyou for your help... :)

Comment: @Tjaden Hess: Thankyou very much !!! I understood my fallacy through severe stress testing of various values practically possible... I understand that if both the x coordinate of R and the encoded message are within the limit of 256 bits then I don't have to worry about the product exceeding the limit. I understood that it is the distributive property of modulo over multiplication that causes this miraculous situation... !!! Thankyou everyone for your love and support !!! :) I was able to solve all my concerns... !!!